# Textview Fit to Screen Width in android for any device

Tags: android

I have TextView which contain text "3D Android Graphics". I want to stretch the text so that it should always fit to screen width of any device provided. Means its text size should be changed according screen size and it should always occupied entire screen width. What should i use to get it done?

Comment: Google keywords: `android autofit textview`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks you.

Comment: You're welcome. But try to improve your googling skills.

Comment: so problem is solved? good ;-)